# JavaFX - Execute a Service x times

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to execute the `Task` from a `Service` a given number of times, but only one after the other.

I tried to simply declare a variable to keep track of the number of times it has already been executed, incrementing it in `service.setOnSucceeded();` but:
`Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`.

I'm stuck here, I surely have missed an obvious point... Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Just make the count variable a field instead of a local variable?

Comment: I thought of it but then it has to be static... And isn't it "dirty", if I may say so? I mean, is there no other solution?

Comment: Why would it have to be static?

Comment: It just sounds like you have the wrong approach from the beginning anyway. Why not just have a single task with a `for` loop, or some other similar solution?

Comment: I've already tried, but for some reason the execution of what's inside the for loop doesn't happen. Step by step seems to reveal it's because of the `getChildren().remove(Node n);` that I call inside which raises an exception handled by the `Thread`, and causing the `Task` to terminate right away...

Comment: So you would execute that line on the FX Application thread each time. But you should be asking about that instead of describing some other workaround you are trying.